# Why does printing strlens not work for a int value?

Tags: c, string, syntax

But it works for a long data type?

for example

```
printf("%i", strlen("test")) -- errors 
printf("%li", strlen("test")) -- this works
```

[image]

Comment: What does "the int errors" mean?

Comment: the program doesn't compile

Comment: The [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) function returns a value of type `size_t`, for which the correct [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format is `%zu`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: "Doesn't compile" ***how***? What errors do you get? Please create a [mcve] and then copy-paste the full and complete error output (as text) into the question body. Also please tell us how you build your program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Doesn't "lead to" UB; it *is* UB

Comment: The posted code doesn't compile for reasons that have nothing to do with `strlen`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Question was clear and it doesn't require more information to answer.

Comment: 1) Don't post text as images. 2) What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: @LazarĐorđević Possibly, but if you search the error message you'll find a lot of previously asked questions that perfectly answers this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strlen` doesn't return an `int` or a `long`, it returns a `size_t`. It appears that in your system, a `size_t` is the same size as a `long`.

But if you're going to print out a `size_t` with `printf`, you're supposed to use `%zu` to do it. That should work (on a new enough compiler to support it) regardless of the relative sizes of `int`, `long` and `size_t`. Before `%zu` was added to the spec (e.g., C89/90) we typically cast the `size_t` to an `unsigned long` before printing it out (and then used `%lu`, obviously).

Comment: "on a new enough compiler to support it" Note the [c] tag description suggests to always assume the latest version unless otherwise specified

Comment: @GovindParmar: Yes, that's why I put that in parentheses. But, there are still enough C89/90 compilers in use that it's a poor idea to simply ignore older compilers (especially since many people don't know what version of the standard their compiler supports). Or to put it simply, the tag description's suggestion is a poor one.

Comment: hi thank you for replying I have another question how can I compare strlens with a number?

Comment: @treeboy3: The usual way would be something like: `if (strlen(foo) < 3) ...` (i.e., it's just a number, so normal comparisons work--though you may get a warning about mixing signed and unsigned numbers, and they're reasonable--you can get strange results if you compare its return to a negative number).

Comment: thank you i have got it now

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` returns `size_t`, not `int`. `size_t` is an unsigned type; `int` is signed.

Passing values that do not match format specifiers is undefined behavior. The correct format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`. (C Standard, § 7.19.6.1:6).